# Toggle div visibility of bootstrap slideshows

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a gallery page that contains many bootstrap carousels, I need to display one at a time through a div visibility swap and I can't seem to get it working.

I've got the multiple carousels working, and I've got the buttons I'd like to use displayed on the right of my page. But all the attempts I've made at toggling visibility onclick has only resulted in none of the galleries showing.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on what I'm dong wrong
Here's the page with the two galleries: http://pink-revolver.com/fleurish/?page_id=149

Thanks!!
Steph

Comment: Shameless bump! I do still need some help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show` and [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) jQuery methods to toggle the visibility of the elements according to your needs.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    });

    $('#myCarousel2').carousel({
        interval: 1500
    });

    $('#hideMe').click(function () {
        $('#myCarousel2').hide()
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/n6Rg8/